# Prove a function is constant. (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose function $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C-\{0\}$ and satisfies $$|f(z)| \le \sqrt {|z|} + \frac{1}{\sqrt {|z|}}.$$ Prove that $f$ is a constant function.

I think it's related to Laurent series representation and ML inequality but I have no idea how to prove it. Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, if you alraedy suspect it's related to the Laurent series you should write that down. Then consider growth of the function as $|z|$ tends to $0$ and $\infty$.

Comment: Im not sure but is this idea correct?
as |z| tends to zero, the negative power terms in the Laurent series has something to do with 1/sqrt(|z|) part (maybe compare the magnitude?) and as |z| tends to infinity, the positive power terms has something to do with sqrt|z| part?

Comment: Oh can it be done by taking the Laurent series, and for the coefficient,( which can be obtained by integrating along a closed loop), take the loop with infinite radius?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the idea. This is a real analysis approach to the problem, there may some complex analysis approach which (I don't know of without doing some research and which) is easier

Comment: Ok i will try. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $g(z)=zf(z)$ can be shown to have a removable singularity at $z=0$ with value $0$. What does that say about $f(z)$ at the origin?

Comment: it means f has a removable singularity at z=0 with arbitrary complex value, but not infinity?

Comment: Anyone can provide a solution or more hints? I've tried for few hours and still im not able to prove it..

Answer (score 7):

Let
$$
 f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n
$$
be the Laurent series for $f$ in $\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$. The
coefficients $a_n, n \in \Bbb Z,$ can be computed as an integral
(compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series)
$$
  a_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} \, dz
$$
where $\gamma$ is any closed curve which surrounds $z=0$ exactly once.
Taking $\gamma$ as a circle with radius $r > 0$ gives the estimate
$$
 |a_n| \le \frac{1}{r^n} \max \{ |f(z)| : |z| = r \} 
 \le  \frac{ \sqrt {r} + \frac{1}{\sqrt {r}}}{r^n} \, .
$$
For fixed $n \ge 1$  and $r \to \infty$  the RHS tends to zero,
and the same is true if $n \le -1$ and $r \to 0$.
Therefore $a_n = 0$ for all $n \ne 0$.

---

Alternatively, you can argue as suggested in the comments.
$g(z) = z f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$ and is
therefore an entire function. From
$$
  |g(z)| \le r^{1/2} + r^{3/2}
$$
the usual estimates of the derivative with the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) show that
$g$ is a polynomial of degree at most one.

So we have
$$
 f(z) = \frac{a z + b}{z}
$$
for some constants $a, b$, and from the growth restriction for $r \to 0$ it
follows that $b = 0$ must hold.

Comment: @Riemann: Thanks for fixing my stupid errors!

Comment: You are welcome, and thanks for your always nice answer!