# Prove that $|f(z)| \leq 2|z|^{\frac{1}{2}} + 3|z|^{\frac{-1}{3}}$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C^*}$ be a holomorphic function, such that, for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ it holds that : $|f(z)|  \leq 2|z|^{\frac{1}{2}} + 3|z|^{\frac{-1}{3}}$

I have to show that f is constant.

I have thought about using the fact that $|a_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{M(r)}{r^{n+1}2}2\pi r$, being

$M(r)= \max\limits_{{\partial B_{r}(z_{0})}}$ $|f|$ $= 2|z|^{\frac{1}{2}} + 3|z|^{\frac{-1}{3}}$

but I don´t really know how to use it or if that would help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: $|z| \ge 1$, we have $|f(z)| \le 2\sqrt |z| +3 \le 2|z|+3$ so $f(z)/z$ is bounded on $|z| \ge 1$ hence $|f(z)| \le C|z|+D, C,D>0$ and now show that implies $f$ linear and then constant using that $f(z)/z \to 0, z \to \infty$

Comment: Similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1746015/42969

Comment: What is $\mathbb C^*?\,$

Comment: @zhw.: $\Bbb C^*$ is sometimes used as a notation for $\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$. I assume however that that should be the *domain* of $f$, i.e. $f: \Bbb C^* \to \Bbb C$.